# YouTubePlayerView stops on screen rotate

Tags: android, youtubeplayer

I am using YouTubePlayerView to load the video.The video plays successfully, but when the screen is rotated, the it stops playing.How do I overcome this problem?It may be a simple thing.I googled but didn't get help but your help is needed...
Below is my code.

Code:

```
youTubePlayerView=findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        onInitializedListener=new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayers=youTubePlayer;
                youTubePlayers.loadVideo("9ZaEPeaucIU");
                youTubePlayers.setFullscreenControlFlags(FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);
                youTubePlayers.setOnFullscreenListener(onFullscreenListener);
            }
            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                }
        };
        onFullscreenListener=new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    time=youTubePlayers.getCurrentTimeMillis();


                }

            }
        };
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                youTubePlayerView.initialize("AI&*$^$^$3634HxbhVM@#$%%^%&%$",onInitializedListener);

                }
        });
```

Layout:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
```

Comment: Try `youTubePlayers.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);` or `youTubePlayers.addFullscreenControlFlag(FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);` in `onInitializationSuccess()`

Comment: I have already done that.It is in the code..Please check it

Comment: Try the `addFullscreenControlFlag()` instead of `setFullscreenControlFlag()`

Comment: No..it didnt work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this on your activity declaration in `AndroidManifext.xml` so that, the activtiy doesn't recreate on orientation change.

```
<activity
        android:name=".NameOfYourActivitiy"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">

</activity>
```

Comment: @jobin add logcat with error on the question please

Comment: I didnt add screen size before.Now it worked.Why is that it is not recommended to include config changes in manifest.

Comment: @jobin great to know! you may accept my answer as it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Added the configChanges in the AndroidManifest file and it worked.

Eg

```
<activity android:label=Activity Name" 
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
  android:name="com.example.blahblah">
```